# pass data frame from one function to another in python

Tags: python, function, dataframe, xlwings

I am using two functions, one to load data and another to get a summary of the same data. However in second function analyze() I get the error df not defined. How do I pass df from loader() to analyze() ?

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
import pandas as pd

def Loader():   
        wb = Workbook.caller() 
        file_path = Range(1,(1,1)).value
        file=pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname='Sheet1')
        df = pd.DataFrame(file)    

def analyze():
        Range('C1').value=df.describe()
```

Comment: I don't see you using `analyze()`.

Comment: Maybe you can start by returning `df` from `Loader`?

Comment: I will call analyze function from Excel using xlwings

Answer (score 1):

With several ways depending on what you want to do. The simplest way is to `return` the `df` from the `Loader()` and then give it to the `analyze()` as an argument:

```
def Loader():   
    wb = Workbook.caller() 
    file_path = Range(1,(1,1)).value
    file=pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname='Sheet1')
    df = pd.DataFrame(file)
    return df

def analyze(df):
    Range('C1').value=df.describe()

# Use it this way
dataFrame = Loader()
analyze(dataframe)
```

Then another way is to have a Loader class like this:

```
class Loader(object):
    def __init__(self):
        wb = Workbook.caller() 
        file_path = Range(1,(1,1)).value
        file=pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname='Sheet1')
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(file)

        # 1) If you want to analyse when you create the object
        # call analyze() here
        self.analyze()

    def analyze(self):
        Range('C1').value=self.df.describe()

    loader = Loader()
    # 2) Otherwise you can keep control of analyze()
    # and call it whenever you want, like this:
    loader.analyze()
```

Of course there are other ways too (like having a global variable for the df).